# Handle OS signal in live endpoints in case of close connections

Tags: go, webserver

I have code that I need to catch OS signal and close the all connections to the database.

In general, below code can handle signal inside main function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {

middleware.
    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "Welcome to the homepage!")
    })

    router.GET("/about", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "This is the about page!")
    })

    router.GET("/contact", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "This is the contact page!")
    })

    router.GET("/help", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "This is the help page!")
    })

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:              ":5000",
        Handler:           router,
        ReadHeaderTimeout: 60 * time.Second,
    }


    go func() {
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            fmt.Printf("listen: %s\n", err)
        }
    }()

    quit := make(chan os.Signal, 2)
    signal.Notify(quit, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-quit

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    if err := srv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Server forced to shutdown: ", err)
    }
    log.Print("Application exit")
}
```

Sometimes endpoints handle bulkdata and is busy.
But I want to be aware how can I handle in live requests if endpoint is busy while server receive SIGTERM.

Comment: This code doesn't close any database connections, it just shuts down the server gracefully. Which may be fine. To provide any better answer I think you'll need to provide more detail - what do you want your application to do when it receives a SIGTERM while it's busy? What is the desired behavior?

Comment: Please improve your question.